# How to run chain of chord successfully in celery?

Tags: python, celery

I am successfully using chord in my system. But, Now I have a case that, I have to run numbers of chord sequentially (second one starts when first ends). So, I was trying to use chain of chords. But it doesn't work for me.

```
@app.task(bind=True)
def some_celery_beat_worker(self):
    feed_chain = []
    for feed in feed_list:
        celery_task_list = [perform single_task.si(url)
                                for url in some_url_list]
        per_feed_chord = chord(celery_task_list, chord_callback.si(feed['_id'], feed['xml_file_name']))
        feed_chain.append(per_feed_chord)
    chain(*feed_chain).delay()
```

Getting this as traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "python3.4/site-packages/celery/app/trace.py", line 374, in trace_task
    R = retval = fun(*args, **kwargs)
  File "python3.4/site-packages/celery/app/trace.py", line 629, in __protected_call__
    return self.run(*args, **kwargs)
  File "workers.py", line 156, in joblist_updater_worker
    chain(*feed_chain).delay()
  File "python3.4/site-packages/celery/canvas.py", line 182, in delay
    return self.apply_async(partial_args, partial_kwargs)
  File "/python3.4/site-packages/celery/canvas.py", line 566, in apply_async
    dict(self.options, **options) if options else self.options))
  File "python3.4/site-packages/celery/canvas.py", line 596, in run
    first_task.apply_async(**options)
  File "python3.4/site-packages/celery/canvas.py", line 1241, in apply_async
    return (self.tasks[0] | body).set(task_id=task_id).apply_async(
KeyError: 0
```

What I need is to fix this particular workflow, or any alternative workflow, which can solve this particular problem (running numbers of chord one after another)

Answer (score 2):

The problem was regarding how I formed the `chain`. It wasn't correct (at least for my celery version), though suggested in number of places.

The approach that works for me.

```
feed_chain = chain()
for feed in feed_list:
    feed_chain |= chord(args)

feed_chain.delay()
```